# string indices must be integers Battle ships codewars kata

Tags: python

Im getting this error when inputting my code in codewars. "Traceback:in module
   in damaged_or_sunk
IndexError: list index out of range". However, when I try my code in spyder3, it works just fine. there are no indicators as to where this error is in the function damaged_or_sunk though.

```
def damaged_or_sunk (board, attacks):        
    a = sum(x.count(1) for x in board)
    b = sum(x.count(2) for x in board)
    c = sum(x.count(3) for x in board) 
    a1 = 0
    b1 = 0
    c1 = 0               
    points = 0
    sunk = 0
    damaged = 0
    not_touched = 0


    for each in attacks:
        rand_row = each[0]
        rand_col = each[1]

        if board[rand_row][rand_col] == 1:
            a1 += 1
        elif board[rand_row][rand_col] == 2:
            b1 += 1
        elif board[rand_row][rand_col] == 3:
            c1 += 1
        else:
            pass

    if a1 == a:
        points += 1
        sunk += 1
    elif a1 == 0:
        points -= 1
        not_touched += 1
    else:
        points += 0.5
        damaged += 1

    if b1 == b:
        points += 1
        sunk += 1
    elif b1 == 0:
        points -= 1
        not_touched += 1
    else:
        points += 0.5
        damaged += 1

    if c1 == c:
        points += 1
        sunk += 1
    elif c1 == 0:
        points -= 1
        not_touched += 1
    else:
        points += 0.5
        damaged += 1    

    return '{\'sunk\': %s, \'damaged\': %s, \'not_touched\': %s, \'points\': %s}' %(sunk, damaged, not_touched, points)
```

Comment: Which line is the error? Provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: it wont print back where the error occurs on codewars though. it just says, in module. and no error occurs in spyder3

Comment: How `attacks` is build? Any code samples?

Comment: attacks is built like this: [[0,1], [1,1], [1,2]]

Answer (score 0):

The couples in `attacks` contains `(x, y)` coordinates which must be list index.

I make the assumption that they are randomly generated, make sure that:

- `0 <= x < len(board[0])`
- `0 <= y < len(board)`
- `all( len(board[0]) ==  len(board[row]) for row in board)`